# Detecting media screen size of parent website from within iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, media-queries

I am trying to change the design of iframe elements that is being hosted on different domain, based on the parent website (the site rendering the iframe).

My specific goal is to change some design components within the iframe for iPhone 5 only (strict iPhone 5). As of now I am getting the width and height by passing the `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` and then passing them as query params in url while loading the iframe. This way I get the exact width in advance and adjust the design elements as per that.

Is there any better way to do this that I am not aware of and I am still to find out how exactly I would target iPhone 5.

I am using this so far for iPhone 5 but no luck:

```
if (window.matchMedia("@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px)").matches) {
  /* jQuery CSS alternations goes here!! */
}
```

NOTE: I and applying css properties within iframe via jQuery .css property. So detection should only be in javascript based on width or whatever is the best way as per your knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try for userAgents. navigator.userAget

Comment: @ShoaibKonnur I just went through it, most of the examples are of detecting browsers. Can you please share an example of screen sizes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JavaScript, if the domain of the `iframe` is the same as the parent's domain, you can use:
`parent.document.body.clientHeight` or `parent.document.body.clientWidth`

If you attempt to use that via an `iframe` in a different domain you will get  a cross-site scripting error, for obvious security reasons.

If the iframe's domain is not the same as the parent's you need to use [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Comment: I have the access of the domain from where if data is being served as well so I have already taken care of CORS issue.

Comment: In that case you can use the post message to transfer data from parent to iframe as linked at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the device viewport dimensions by using `window.screen.height` and `window.screen.width`. It works correctly even from an iframe.

```html
<iframe width="100" height="40" srcdoc="<script>
    document.writeln(window.screen.width,'x',window.screen.height)
    </script>">
</iframe>
```

Comment: window.innerWidth works pretty well for me too